# Update a value on select of option

Tags: jquery, html

How can the value of my textbox update or change depending on the option that is selected by the user? Because as of the moment, when I first choose an option in Dropdown1 then chooses an option on Dropdown2, a value will show in my textbox, but if I change my choice on dropdown1, the value in the textbox won't change unless, I re-select again on my Dropdown2.

```
    <select name="menu" id="select1">
                        <option value="A">A</option>
                        <option value="B">B</option>
                        <option value="C">C</option>
                        <option value="D">D</option>
                </select>
                <select name="menu2" id="select2" onchange="changetxt3()"> 
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>

                <input type="text" id="txt6"/>

**jquery**

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select1").change(function(){
        if($(event.target).val() == 'A'){
                $("#select2").change(function(){
                    if($(event.target).val() == '1'){
                        $('#txt6').val('250.00');
                    }else{
                        $('#txt6').val('250.00');
                    }
                }); 
            }else if($(event.target).val() == 'B'){
                $("#select2").change(function(){
                    if($(event.target).val() == '1'){
                        $('#txt6').val('50.00');
                    } else{
                        $('#txt6').val('50.00');
                    }
                });
                }else
                if($(event.target).val() == 'C'){
                    $("#select2").change(function(){
                    if($(event.target).val() == '1'){
                        $('#txt6').val('103.00');
                    } else{
                        $('#txt6').val('103.00');
                    }
                });
            }else
        {
            $("#select2").change(function(){
                    if($(event.target).val() == '1'){
                        $('#txt6').val('186.00');
                    } else{
                        $('#txt6').val('186.00');
                    }
                });
        }
    });
});
```

See the jsfiddle

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scoj2k2m/)

Comment: This is the messiest code I've ever seen.

Comment: You need to strip out all the change handlers from inside `if` statements. The `if` logic should be inside the handlers, not wrapping them. Start all over again. One change handler for each select. Check the value of other select directly when the change occurs

Comment: `event` is undefined. You need to use `function(event) {...}`;

Comment: Is there any reason why all your inner `if` statements all set the same value regardless of true or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't take this as offensive, but your code is pretty cancerous so I changed it a *little* bit.

```js
$(function() {
    var val1, val2;
    $("#select1").change(function() {
        switch ($(event.target).val())
        {
            case 'A':
                val1 = '250.00';
                val2 = '250.00';
                break;
            case 'B':
                val1 = '50.00';
                val2 = '50.00';
                break;
            case 'C':
                val1 = '103.00';
                val2 = '103.00';
                break;
            default:
                val1 = '186.00';
                val2 = '186.00';
                break;
        }
        update();
    });
    
    $("#select2").change(function(event) {
        update();
    });
    
    function update()
    {
        if ($('#select2').val() == '1')
        {
            $('#txt6').val(val1);
        } else {
            $('#txt6').val(val2);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="menu" id="select1">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<select name="menu2" id="select2" onchange="changetxt3()"> 
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
    
    <input type="text" id="txt6"/>
```

With all the wonderful IDE's on the market, or even something as simple as Notepad++, I'm surprised that people can't even indent properly.

Nothing was invoked in the original code that would change the textbox's value when `$('#select1')` changed. I added a function to call in that case. To see a something on your textbox when you change `$('#select2')`, you'll need `val1` and `val2` to be different. I didn't make them different because you didn't on your original code.